# Establishment of Ownership of Spoils of war & captives

Tags: fiqh, slavery, jihad, war, usool-ul-fiqh

السلام عليكم

When is ownership of spoils of war and captives established for soldiers? Do spoils of war and captives have to be transferred from Dar al Harb to Dar Al Islam before establishing ownership?

Did any Madhab allow the distribution of spoils of war & captives among soldiers in Dar Al Harb?